# Unable to set featured image

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, post-thumbnails

I was customizing theme for some body, basically i just added a taxonomy for the custom post type client which was allready there. There were already 6 posts ,
I added like 30 more posts , set featured image ,page attributes title , selcted taxonomy term etc.

But suddenly now i am unable to add featured image for the posts.

when i try to set featured image, i am unable to see images in media library

[image]

Even if i select some image after uploading or from the on already there then when i hit publish, browser keeps on processing and never stops..

If i go to see if the post i.e client has been saved, the post is saved but when i open but if i try to open it again i am not able to see the image.

So i thought may be the issue with theme. i tried switching to default theme twentyfourteen , Now i tried the same process for normal post but again i don't see any thing in media library, same as in above image

Never faced any problem like that, and i am on deadline.

May the server issue, but please help

Comment: Did you make these changes in the theme or as a plugin? Quick test - comment out your edits or revert to a backup.  Add sections of code back until you find the problem.

Comment: Did you check your custom post type settings for errors?

Comment: hey  guys thanks for all the help. But i just went to sleep , and now i see its working fine

Answer (score 2):

Try checking your Browsers Javascript console, Media Library in WordPress is heavily depended on javascript's such as jQuery.

also if your Javascript is broken due to concatenation, then add the below line in your `wp-config.php` file.

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

Or you can even try re-installing WordPress.

Comment: hey  guys thanks for all the help. But i just went to sleep , and now i see its working fine

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's something wrong with the images or the media path WordPress is using to search for the files. Try taking a look at your FTP and check if the path is correct and all the files are OK.

Comment: hey  guys thanks for all the help. But i just went to sleep , and now i see its working fine